# not geospatial filtering with the algolia_helpers_flutter package

Tags: flutter, search, indexing, geospatial, algolia

I started integrating Algolia in my flutter application with the algolia _helpers_flutter package. But in the documentation I can't find it.to be brief I don't know how to do geospatial filtering with this package instead of using the algolia Package. because I have already evolved a lot with filtering using the Package algolia_search_flutter

filter instances filter instances from my index not geolocation